# Overridden ID in CSS shows only portion of image instead of full image

Tags: css, html

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
<img id="logo-img">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#logo-img {
background: url("google.png") no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

When I'm trying to specify image using CSS,it only shows the portion of the image instead of scaling it accordinlgly(100x100 starting from top-left corner).Why?Shouldn't it be scaled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `background-image` doesn't scale by default. Look at the `background-size` property. Common values that will cause the image to scale are `cover`, `contain`, and `100%`. You can read more about scaling background images here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images

Depending on the aspect ratio of the image compared to element the image is a `background` of, you may also want to modify the `background-position` property, too. Read more about that here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: So if I wanted to scale background image I would need to use background-size property in combination with height and width properties?

Comment: With your existing markup, yes. Using `background-size` is necessary to scale a background image. Assigning a `height` and `width` to the element isn't necessary if the element has content (since the content will give the element a height/width), but you're assigning a background to an empty element, so you will need to specify a height/width. A background won't give an element a height/width.